# A C# regex question: retrieve Google search results

Tags: c#, regex

I want to store Google search results (both title and link) into database. HTML code of search results is like:

```
<br/>
```

THETITLE

And each page has 10 results. Can anyone show me how to retrieve `THEURL` and `THETITLE`?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to give [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) a try. An HTML parser is correct way to read HTML content, [not regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

**BUT**, If you wanna try for your own risk:

```
<h3 class=r><a .*? href="(?<url>[^"]*)".*?>(?<title>.*?)</a></h3>
```

You'll have problems with:

- Line breaks
- Unmatched tags
- Minor HTML changes

So, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I would not recommend using regex for this, use the '[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=33903)' to do the parsing of the HTML document.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Google AJAX Search API instead.  It will be easier on both you and Google's servers.  There are some instructions for using it [outside JavaScript environments](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje_snippets).  They don't give a C# example, but it shouldn't be difficult to adapt to your needs using one of the JSON APIs for C#.

If you do stick with HTML, I also recommend HTML Agility Pack.

You should also think about caching so you minimize both stale data and unnecessary requests.